# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'introduce'

Tags: python, классы

Есть два объекта, при передаче их в `for` и вызове метода класса, в терминал выкидывается ошибка - `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'introduce'`. С чем это может быть связано?

```
class Personal_Data:
       def __init__(self, name, surname, phone_number):
           self.name = name
           self.surname = surname
           self.phone_number = phone_number

       def introduce(self):
           print("Имя: {0}, Фамилия: {1}, Номер телефона       {2}".format(self.name, self.surname, self.phone_number))

Vasiliy = Personal_Data('Vasiliy', 'Valakas', '88005553535'),
Ivan = Personal_Data('Ivan', 'Ivanov', '88005553535')
members = [Vasiliy, Ivan]

print("Что можно сделать: Посмотреть контакты (наберите 'контакты'), Добавить новый контакт ('добавить'), Удалить контакт ('удалить')")

void = input("Что будем делать --> ")
if void != void.lower():
  void = void.lower() # Если в строке есть символы с верхним регистром, то они переводятся в нижний 

if void == 'контакты':
  for member in members:
    member.introduce()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана запятой в конце следующей строки:

```
Vasiliy = Personal_Data('Vasiliy', 'Valakas', '88005553535'),
```

---

Пример:

```
In [133]: a = 1,

In [134]: a
Out[134]: (1,)

In [135]: type(a)
Out[135]: tuple
```

Answer (score 5):

Все дело в запятой:

```
Vasiliy = Personal_Data('Vasiliy', 'Valakas', '88005553535'), # <--
Ivan = Personal_Data('Ivan', 'Ivanov', '88005553535')
```

которая превращает одиночный объект в tuple.

```
print(Vasiliy)
```

выведет

```
(<__main__.Personal_Data object at 0x7fcf9736e780>,)
```

Уберите запятую, и все заработает как надо.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно убрать запятую в конце строчки с Василием.

Answer (score 2):

В конце 10 строки,где ты создал объект valiliy лишняя запятая.Будь внимательнее)